# Add padding 0 before single character in javascript clock

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function clock(){ 
  var d = new Date(); 
  var h = d.getHours(); 
  var m = d.getMinutes(); 
  var s = d.getSeconds(); 
  $('#clock').html(", "+h+"<span class='colon'>:</span>"+m+"<span class='colon'>:</span>"+s); 
//  $('.colon').fadeTo(1000, .2); 
  setTimeout(clock, 1000); 
}
```

Above is the javascript , which i used to display a clock on my Webapplication.it is working fine but now i want that For any single digit value, the value should be padding 0 before the actual value. 
For example
12:15:05,
12:15:15,
12:05:10,
02:05:09

Currently it is showing like this:-
12:15:5,
12:15:15,
12:5:10,
2:5:9

Any help or suggestion that how i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var s = d.getSeconds();
    if (parseInt(h) < 10)
       h = "0" + h;
    if (parseInt(m) < 10)
       m = "0" + m;
    if (parseInt(s) < 10)
       s = "0" + s;
$('#clock').html(", " + 
       h + "<span class='colon'>:</span>" + 
       m + "<span class='colon'>:</span>" + 
       s);
setTimeout(clock, 1000);
```

Just add conditional checks on those `h, m and s`

Comment: I suggest adding a radix to `parseInt` to avoid JS from misinterpreting what you want to convert.

Answer (score 2):

Make a little helper function and call that:

```
function pad(n)
{
  return (pad < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple "if less than 10" conditional should do.

```
if(value<10){
    //it must be 1 digit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this,

```
var d = new Date(); 
var h = d.getHours(); 
h = h+''; // it will give string
if(h.length == 1) { 
h = "0"+h
}
```